# Troubleshooting vim configuration warnings

Tags: vim

I've been messing with vim configuration recently, and now when I open the first file in gVim, I see some warnings that disappear quickly. Where else can I see them and see what's wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try one of the following:

1. After starting vim, use `:messages` command. It will show you all messages (except that were echoed with `echo` or `echon`).
2. Redirect vim output to some file: `vim -c 'qa!' > messages.log`.
3. Start vim using `vim --cmd 'redir! > messages.log' -c 'redir END' -c 'qa!'`, then observe `messages.log`.

Comment: Thanks, :messages does it. The other two did not work for me in console.